# PostgreSQL concurrent row update

Tags: postgresql

Can someone say how PostgreSQL behaves when i'm trying to update same row but different fields at the same time (concurrently)? What transaction level it's using

Comment: Read this [Concurrency Control](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html), it should have the answers you need.

Answer (score 0):

When you update a row, the *whole row* is locked until the end of the database transaction. So the first update will block the second one, even if they modify different columns. This is independent of the transaction isolation level.